# PostgreSQL duplicate multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, internationalization

There is an app that needs to be translatable by the user (admin) through the UI (contenteditable=true).
For that I created a postgres (PostgreSQL Version 13.5) database with a table which holds the following:

```
|lang|key |createdby|version|value|
|----| ---| ---  | --- | --- |
|en | key.to.value |someone| 4 | some english words|
|en | key.to.value |someone| 3 | some egnlish words|
|en | key.to.value |someone| 42 | some english words|
|de | key.to.value|someone|12|some german words|
|de | key.to.value|someone|23456|some german words|
```

lang key and version are the primary key.

the types of each columns are text. The table also holds all older versions of an entry to be able to switch to older versions if needed.

now I have to add the possibility to create a new language which has the highest versions data of the English rows but 'new language' (Spanish, Portuguese, whatever) as lang and '1' as version.
The user will be able to choose "add new language" in the UI and gets the English values to start the translation.

***EDIT***
I need to duplicate every English row with the highest version and set lang to 'whateEverLanguage' and version to version '1'

that was my last try:

```sql
insert into strings 
(lang, key, createdby, version, value) 
values 
(
(select 'esp'),
(select key from strings where lang='en' and version = (select max(version) from strings where lang='en')), 
(select createdby from strings where lang='en' and version = (select max(version) from strings where lang='en')),
(select version from strings where lang='en' and version = (select max(version) from strings where lang='en')),
(select value from strings where lang='en' and version = (select max(version) from strings where lang='en')));
```

I just started with databases in general about 1 week ago.
I'm depressed about struggling with that so please please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the last version of the 'en' language for every key, you need to filter the rows where `lang = 'en'`, group the rows by `key`, order the grouped rows by `version DESC`, select the first row of the group by using an aggregate function, for instance `array_agg()` :

```
SELECT key
     , (array_agg(value ORDER BY version DESC))[1]
  FROM strings
 WHERE lang = 'en'
 GROUP BY key
```

If you only want the 'en' value for one `specific_key` only, you can filter on that key in addition :

```
SELECT key
     , (array_agg(value ORDER BY version DESC))[1]
  FROM strings
 WHERE key = specific_key
   AND lang = 'en'
 GROUP BY key
```

If you want to insert new rows, then you can do :

```
insert into strings (lang, key, createdby, version, value) 
select 'spanish'
     , key
     , (array_agg(createdby order by version desc))[1]
     , '1'
     , (array_agg(value order by version desc))[1]
  from strings
  where lang = 'en' 
  group by key
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d740477224d5710a47b69b1123410674)

Comment: Thank you! but i can't figure it out.
i tried the following:
'insert into strings (lang, key, createdby, version, value) values ('spanish', (select (array_agg(key order by version desc))[1] as key from strings where lang = 'en' group by key
), (select (array_agg(createdby order by version desc))[1] as createdby from strings where lang = 'de' group by createdby
),'1' , (select (array_agg(value order by version desc))[1] as value from strings where lang = 'de' group by value
)); '
but get the error:
'ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000'

Comment: You can't mix a `values()` clause and `select` clause in the same `insert` statement, either the first one or the second one. see the answer updated.